# Updating an array with data retrieved and updated inside a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, dns

I am getting data from an array using the .reduce function, I am not sure if this is the best way to do it, however it is the only way that works at the moment thanks to some assistance I received on another post.

I don't know how to update the array with the changes made in the function,the return array ignores the changes made.

The data is provided by a router and updated every second.

```
var data    =  [
 {  macProtocol: 'ip',
    ipProtocol: 'udp',
    dstAddress: '1.1.1.1',
    tx: '0',
    rx: '384'},
 {  macProtocol: 'ip',
    ipProtocol: 'udp',
    dstAddress: '8.8.8.8',
    tx: '384',
    rx: '384'},
 {  macProtocol: 'ip',
    ipProtocol: 'udp',
    dstAddress: '1.1.1.1',
    tx: '384',
    rx: '384',},
];


// We resolve the DNS and output the final array
let DNSvariable = result.reduce((arr, currentValue) => {

    var setIP = currentValue.dstAddress;

    var dns = require('dns');
    dns.setServers([
        '8.8.8.8', 
    ]);

    // Test that IP's are being received correctly. 
    console.log(setIP);

// Resolve the IP addresses
dns.reverse(setIP, (err, address) => {
     currentValue.dstAddress = address;

    // If I log the currentValue inside this function everything looks correct, it has updated the values in the full array. I need to push this array, into the returned array. 

});

return arr;
}, []);

// Logging the variable produces the array with the original IP
console.log(DNSvariable);
```

I Would like the console.log(DNSvariable); to return the array with the resolved names, at the moment it is returning the addresses. I just don't know how to update the array.

Expected result would be:

```
var data    =  [
 {  macProtocol: 'ip',
    ipProtocol: 'udp',
    dstAddress: 'one.one.one.one',
    tx: '0',
    rx: '384'},
 {  macProtocol: 'ip',
    ipProtocol: 'udp',
    dstAddress: 'dns.google',
    tx: '384',
    rx: '384'},
 {  macProtocol: 'ip',
    ipProtocol: 'udp',
    dstAddress: 'one.one.one.one',
    tx: '384',
    rx: '384',},
];
```

I apologise if any of this is incorrect or posted incorrectly.

Edit: The reason I am using the reduce function, is because every other method of accessing the dstAddress has not returned the data in a way that has worked with the dns function. It definitely doesn't appear to be the correct way to do it.

Comment: I don't understand what the code is supposed to do. `Array.reduce` is typically used to turn an array into a single value; is this really what you want to do? Is this about getting hostnames from IP addresses? Where is `result` coming from? Is `data` an example of what the router data looks like?

Comment: data is exactly what the router is providing. I want to take that data, and change the IP into the resolved host name and use it for something else. I will update the post with my expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use the new Promises api

```
const { Resolver } = require('dns').promises;
const resolver = new Resolver();
resolver.setServers(['8.8.8.8']);
```

Next, resolve all addresses like this:

```
async function main() {
    const promises = data.map(item => resolver.reverse(item.dstAddress));
    const hostNames = await Promise.all(promises);
    data.forEach((item, i) => {
        item.dstAddress = hostNames[i];
    });
    console.log(data);
}

main();
```

First we construct an array of all resolve Promises. Next we wait for all Promises being resolved. Finally, we overwrite `.dstAddress` with each corresponding result.

**Edit:**

Since `Promise.all` fails if a single Promise fails, here's an alternate version that wraps `dns.reverse` in a custom Promise:

```
const dns = require('dns');
dns.setServers(['8.8.8.8']);
const reverser = (ipAddress) => new Promise(resolve => {
  dns.reverse(ipAddress, (err, hostname) => {
    if (err) resolve(ipAddress);
    else resolve(hostname);
  });
});
```

As you can see, a failure to resolve the IP simply returns the IP; this way every Promise will resolve, even if `dns.reverse` itself fails.

Use like this:

```
async function main() {
  const promises = data.map(item => reverser(item.dstAddress));
  const hostnames = await Promise.all(promises);
  data.forEach((item, i) => {
    item.dstAddress = hostnames[i];
  });
  console.log(data);
}

main();
```

Comment: Thanks this looks good, however I get this error, am I supposed to install or include something?

```javascript
const { Resolver } = require('dns').promises;
        ^

TypeError: Cannot destructure property `Resolver` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
```

Comment: I guess you need to update your node version maybe? Mine is `10.10.0`

Comment: @Matthew I added a fallback for older node versions without `dns.promises`

Comment: @Matthew No problem ;)

Comment: So this is working well when it works, however it comes up with this error more often than not: I am not sure if I need to create a new post for this.
-----------------------------------------------------------
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: getHostByAddr ENOTFOUND 121.162.224.54
----------------------------------------------------------
(node:18316) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().

Comment: Okay this happens whenever there is a IP address that does not have a reverse DNS record, I assume I need to set up some form of catch to allow for this and output something to replace it?

Comment: @Matthew I see; what do you want to do if the IP cannot be resolved? Keep it?

Comment: @Matthew I put a new version in the **edit** part that will always work.

Answer (score 1):

Reduce doesn't look perfect for your usecase. I'd advise using the 'map' method.
For example,

if there is a array,

```
var arr1=[{a:1},{a:3},{a:4}]
```

You need another array with some modified records:

```
var arr2=arr1.map((elem)=>{ 
  const elem2={...elem}
  elem2.b=5;
  return elem2;
})


console.log('Array1:',arr1)
console.log('Array2:',arr2)
```

Result:

```
'Array1:' [ { a: 1 }, { a: 3 }, { a: 4 } ]
'Array2:' [ { a: 1, b: 5 }, { a: 3, b: 5 }, { a: 4, b: 5 } ]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use reduce, then instead of

`return arr`

try

`return [...arr, currentValue]`

However, I think you would be better served with a map:

```
let DNSvariable = result.map((currentValue) => {

    var setIP = currentValue.dstAddress;

    var dns = require('dns');
    dns.setServers([
        '8.8.8.8', 
    ]);

    dns.reverse(setIP, (err, address) => {
        currentValue.dstAddress = address;
    });

    return currentValue;
});
```

I would also suggest moving these lines outside of your function as they only need to be called once.

```
var dns = require('dns');
dns.setServers([
    '8.8.8.8', 
]);
```

Comment: Thanks this looked really good, however it produces the same result as the original code. the output of DNSvariable has the IP instead of the resolved name.